# How to do this better than 6x OR statements

Tags: php, smarty

I'm completely new to programming, and I couldn't find an answer for this or maybe I simply didn't understand the answer.

Either way, this is my code. How could I change this so that it doesn't use 6 or-statements?

```
 {if $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI == '/home-product.php?id_product=1' 
OR $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI == '/home-product.php?id_product=2'
OR $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI == '/home-product.php?id_product=3'
OR $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI == '/home-product.php?id_product=4'
OR $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI == '/home-product.php?id_product=5'
OR $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI == '/home-product.php?id_product=6'}
```

Comment: You'd better ask this on code review : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `{if in_array($smarty.server.REQUEST_URI, array('url1', 'url2', ..., 'url6')}`

Comment: Hi Patrick, i attempted to use your solution however it's not working for me, so obviously im doing something wrong. Can you hint me in the right direction ?

{if in_array($smarty.server.REQUEST_URI, array('/home-product.php?id_product=1', '/home-product.php?id_product=2', '/home-product.php?id_product=3', '/home-product.php?id_product=4', '/home-product.php?id_product=5', /home-product.php?id_product=6')}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access GET variables directly in Smarty.

```
{if in_array($smarty.get.id_product, range(1,6))}
    is in array
{else}
    is not in array
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should not do such things in Smarty. You should do it in PHP using for example `in_array`. Smarty is just for displaying data and not for such comparisons.

You could also use Smarty syntax as:

```
{assign var="test" value ="5"}

{if in_array($test, array(1,2,5,8))}
is in array
{else}
is not in array
{/if}
```

**EDIT**

In this case it could simple be:

```
{if in_array($smarty.server.REQUEST_URI, 
    array(
    '/home-product.php?id_product=1',
    '/home-product.php?id_product=2',
    '/home-product.php?id_product=3',
    '/home-product.php?id_product=4',
    '/home-product.php?id_product=5',
    '/home-product.php?id_product=6'
    ))}
is in array
{else}
is not in array
{/if}
```

Comment: Hey Marcin,

I appreciate your attempt to help me, but im not sure i quite yet know how to implement that. Here's my attempt

{assign var="test" value"$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI "}
{if in_array($test, array(/home-product.php?id_product=1,/home-product.php?id_product=2,/home-product.php?id_product=3,/home-product.php?id_product=4,/home-product.php?id_product=5,/home-product.php?id_product=6))}

Answer (score 0):

```
$num = substr($smarty.server.REQUEST_URI, -1);
if ($num > 0 AND $num < 7) { /* TRUE */ }
```

Obviously this is PHP and not Smarty Syntax.

Comment: Ironically one of the tags is PHP and nowhere does it mention he wants Smarty Code.

Comment: True, but why do you think that in PHP you will be able to use `$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI` syntax?

Comment: Because I write my own Templating Engines instead of using public ones thus have never had experience with Smarty, the code I gave could at least give him the methodology of shortening his IF OR statement without being given the actual code to do it. More of a learning opp.